# Why does function modify list and how can I keep it from happening?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm calling a function in Python 3.7.x and passing a list to it.  I do *not* want the list modified. Inside the function, I make a copy of the list and modify that.

After the function completes, the original list passed to the function has been modified.  Why is that happening and how can I prevent it?

Here is the code

```
def append_string(alist, astring):
    a_new_list = alist
    a_new_list.append(astring)
    return a_new_list
my_list = ["a", "b"]
my_string = "c"
my_new_list = append_string(my_list, my_string)
print(my_list)
print(my_new_list)
```

Here is the output. Notice that `my_list` has been modified.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I would have expected `my_list` to remain unmodified and the `my_new_list` to contain the concatenation of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a_new_list = alist` doesn't make a copy of the list, it just adds a new name reference to the same list.

To copy the list you can choose from a couple of options

```py
a_new_list = alist[:]

from copy import copy
a_new_list = copy(alist)
```

**Edit**

After writing this I looked and there is a duplicate question here: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list). The accepted answer there is much better and more detailed *and* lists more options that I didn't actually know about.

Comment: You should note that using `copy` creates a shallow copy. For 1-d lists of numbers, this is not a problem. But it will be a problem if you have a list of lists. Ex: `a=[0]; b=[a]; c=copy(b)`. Then `c is b` returns False (as expected), but `c[0] is b[0]` returns True --> The internal list is **not** copied. If this is an issue, use `copy.deepcopy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try,

In your function, you take a list and an object as input. After you append the item to provided input, you return back the list.

What is happening is,

1. you are sending a list's C pointer to the function
2. you add an item to the list
3. you are returning the list's C pointer

```
>>> def append_string(alist, astring):
...     a_new_list = alist
...     a_new_list.append(astring)
...     print(id(a_new_list)) # print the list's id
...     return a_new_list
...
>>>
>>> alist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> id(alist)
140215330632840
>>>
>>> 
>>> append_string(alist, 'd') # this 
140215330632840
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
>>> id(append_string(alist, 'd'))
140215330632840
140215330632840
>>>
```

As you see, the `id` of the list is just moving in and out of the function. To have an exact copy of the list, you can use `deepcopy` function in python inbuilt library `copy`

**Note:** `id` function - Return the identity of an object. This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.